# Is there a limit for stream length in c#?

Tags: c#, stream

I need to read a stream in this way:

```
using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.getResponse())
{
  using(Stream answer = response.getResponseStream())
  {
    // waiting for a while to read next
  }
}
```

However, I don't know the stream length. According Fiddler the stream length is greater than 15,000,000 bytes.

Is there a length limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's  9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes (8,388,608 terrabytes)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Can you post your source? Thanks

Comment: `Stream.Length` is an `Int64`; Kieren has given you `Int64.MaxValue`. You might want to look at [`HttpWebResponse.ContentLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength.aspx) though.

Answer (score 3):

There is no (sane) limit on stream length.

You're looking for the HTTP response's `ContentLength` property.

Answer (score 2):

[`Stream.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length.aspx) is a `long`, so its (positive) limit is `2^63`. It should be OK for you.

Answer (score -1):

I have to read into memory a 2.9 Gbytes encrypted file and decrypt it.  During the read into memory ( Using Bouncy Castle ), I get a Stream Length Limit Exception running in 64 bit mode.  If I decrypt the file from the encrypted data file to another file, then read it into memory using a FileReader, I do not get the error and end up with the entire file in memory.  I really need to decrypt directly into memory as the customer doesn't want PII data to reside on disk at any time, unencrypted.  What would cause this Stream Length Exception, then?