# How do I examine contents of a stream before assigning it to string?

Tags: .net

I am receiving an `HttpWebResponse` containing both XML and a `FileStream` of unknown length. I know that streams can contain a [very large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281470/) amount of bytes, but the upper limits of strings are [significantly smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/). Inside the XML I have a `<size>` tag that tells me how big the `FileStream` is.

Is it possible to get the information from the `<size>` prior to assigning the stream contents to a string? I want to prevent unhandled exceptions when I `myXMLresponse=myStream.ReadToEnd`, if the service sends me something bigger than it should.

Comment: You could certain just read some of the bytes, like with `ReadLine` before reading the rest of the stream.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I like your idea: instead of examining *before* assigning to a string, examine *while* assigning to string, examining one line at a time.